Find the maximum of an expression under the logconcave assumption
Let $F(v)$ be a cdf over $\left[0,v_{max}\right]$, $1-F(v)$ is logconcave. The corresponding density function is $f(v)$. Let $p^m$ solve $1-F(v)-f(v)v=0$ (it is a FOC of a profit maximization problem).
For any given constant $a$ such that $0 <a < c \leq p^m$, what is the number $b$ that maximizes the following expression for $b \in \left[a, c\right]$?
\begin{equation*}
  \frac{\left[\int^c_b (1-F(v)-f(v)v) dv \right] \left[ \int^b_a (1-F(v))dv\right]}{\int^b_a (1-F(v)-f(v)v) dv } 
\end{equation*}
P.S. I have tried normal, exponential, and Weibull distributions (with some examples), the expression is decreasing in $b$ and convex, thus maximized at $b=a$.
